# W3C validator: "Attribute at_v_i not allowed on element input at this point."

Tags: html, attributes, w3c-validation, html-input

```
<input class="filtered a_name" id="attribute_value_1560" type="checkbox" name="attribute_value[156][]" at_v_i="156_A+++/A++" value="A+++/A++">

<table>
<?php foreach($attribute_value['values'] as $i => $value) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input class="filtered a_name"
                   id="attribute_value_<?php echo $attribute_value_id . $i; ?>"
                   type="checkbox" name="attribute_value[<?php echo $attribute_value_id?>][]"
                   at_v_i="<?php echo $attribute_value_id . '_' . $value; ?>"
                   value="<?php echo $value ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for="attribute_value_<?php echo $attribute_value_id . $i; ?>"
                   at_v_t="<?php echo $attribute_value_id . '_' . htmlspecialchars(preg_replace('/\s+|\n|\r|\s+$/m', '_', $value)); ?>"
                   data-value="<?php echo $value; ?>"
                   value="<?php echo $value ?>"><?php echo $value?></label>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

I'm getting this error:

> Attribute at_v_i not allowed on element input at this point.

How can I solve this?

Comment: What is your surrounding context? `at_v_i` is surely not a valid HTML attribute for the `input` element.

Comment: Hi @zx485 ! Thx for ur answer. I added my source code to the post. It's about some filters in an opencart store.